# Foreach loop full execution and stop the rest of the script

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a product table from where I am checking that quantity for respective product id(s) is valid or not..

this is the code snippet :

```
$pids = explode(',',$pid); /*in the form of 2,3,4.....*/ /*$pid->product_id*/
$q = explode(',',$q_total); /*in the form of 2,3,4.....*/ /*$q->quantity*/


/*checking start*/

foreach($pids as $index => $ps){
  $quants = $q[$index];
  $sql = $stsp->query("SELECT quantity FROM product WHERE id='$ps'");
  $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $quantity_rem = $row['quantity'];
  if($quants > $quantity_rem){
    $array = array();
    $array['errquant'] = 'wrong_quant';
    $array['error_pr'] = $ps;
    echo json_encode($array);
    exit;  /*stop the rest of the code from executing*/
   }

} 

  /*rest of the code outside the loop*/
```

So here what is happening is it checks the quantity (`$quantity_rem`) from table of a product id and if that quantity is less than the quantity given (`$q`), then the script stops and echo the product id..

But I have more that 1 product .. It's not checking the rest since whenever there is a fault it stops and echo out. I want to check all the products and echo out the product id(s) and stop  the rest of the script outside the loop..

Help needed!
Thanks.

and please don't talk to me about sql injection because i know it is vulnerable and i will  take care of that..

Comment: why do you stop inside then?

Comment: You should be using [parameter binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) instead of just blindly inserting strings into your query. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: because whenever the if statement is true i don't want the rest of the code outside the loop to be executed.. whenever if statement is false then it can execute..

Comment: You are stopping INSIDE while you want to stop the OUTSIDE code. Don't you find it quite illogical?

Comment: yes I find it illogical but since I am unable to check whether the if statement is true outside the loop i did it.. Actually I don't know how to check that outside the loop.. You could try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pids = explode(',',$pid); /*in the form of 2,3,4.....*/ /*$pid->product_id*/
$q = explode(',',$q_total); /*in the form of 2,3,4.....*/ /*$q->quantity*/


/*checking start*/

$errors  = array();

foreach($pids as $index => $ps){
  $quants = $q[$index];
  $sql = $stsp->query("SELECT quantity FROM product WHERE id='$ps'");
  $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $quantity_rem = $row['quantity'];
  if($quants > $quantity_rem){
    $array = array();
    $array['errquant'] = 'wrong_quant';
    $array['error_pr'] = $ps;
    $errors[] = $array;
   }

} 


echo json_encode($errors);
```

Comment: how to know which productid is in the error? I have to get it within ajax response.

Comment: The product id is in error_pr, you can use this.

So in javascript you should have an array of objects. Each object has an error_pr property with the product ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($pids as $index => $ps){
  $quants = $q[$index];
  $sql = $stsp->query("SELECT quantity FROM product WHERE id='$ps'");
  $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $quantity_rem = $row['quantity'];
    $array = array();
  if($quants > $quantity_rem){

    $array[$ps]['errquant'] = 'wrong_quant'; 

  // note little change - you will get array with product ids as key 
  //and qty error assigned to them

   }
echo json_encode($array);
 exit;  /*stop the rest of the code from executing*/
```

Comment: how to get it back in the ajax response..? because I haven't worked with 2 dimensional array ..